# Does Ubuntu Touch allow custom keyboards?

Tags: keyboard, ubuntu-touch

Does Ubuntu Touch allow the possibility of a custom keyboard (as is possible on Android)?  By this I mean a proprietary "keyboard app" that you can install from a 3rd party developer.

There at least a few options for on-screen keyboards in normal Ubuntu, but I can't find out whether it is possible to use the same virtual keyboard in Ubuntu Touch and in normal Ubuntu.  Is this something that might be resolved in 15.04?

I would like to help a free 3rd party app maker to port their keyboard to Ubuntu, but if I can't get something to work for Touch (all devices) I see no point...

Comment: I think it's possible. I think maliit is a possibility. Also it should be possible to add a modified language-specific layout. I hope that's a way to get the right characters in the right place with the stock keyboard, but I haven't managed to do this, though. The manuals for doing this are a bit unclear, and I don't know enough about it.